# How to get list of HID devices in a Swift/Cocoa application?

Tags: swift, hid, iokit

The following code works perfectly to get a list of connected HID devices:

```
import Foundation
import IOKit
import IOKit.usb
import IOKit.hid

private func createDeviceMatchingDictionary( usagePage: Int, usage: Int) -> CFMutableDictionary {
    let dict = [
        kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey: usage,
        kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey: usagePage
        ] as NSDictionary

    return dict.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary;
}

let manager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone));
let keyboard = createDeviceMatchingDictionary(usagePage: kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, usage: kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard)

IOHIDManagerOpen(manager, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone) )
IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(manager, keyboard)

let devices = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(manager)

if (devices != nil) {
    print("Found devices!")
}
else {
    print("Did not find any devices :(")
}
```

If I take that same code and put it in a Cocoa application, inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, then `devices` is `nil`.

How can I get a list of devices in a Cocoa application??

Why does `IOHIDManagerCopyDevices()` return nothing only when run inside a Cocoa application? What am I missing?

Comment: How can I change this to detect usb or serial devices?

Comment: Where did you get this code to run perfectly?

Comment: @MarcoLuglio This was from a project that I was working on a couple years ago that can be found here: https://github.com/chaimpeck/CoolerMaster-NumLock-Toggle

Comment: see here in particular: https://github.com/chaimpeck/CoolerMaster-NumLock-Toggle/blob/645bf5f14b33e1563b9648a2e5cd82a7b5ec5974/CoolerMasterNumLockToggle/setleds.c#L186

Answer (score 7):

AHA!

There is a `.entitlements` file included in the XCode project and you need to add a row for `com.apple.security.device.usb` and set it to "YES" for a Cocoa project.

Comment: I just added this but it did not fix things for me.  Any idea what could be the problem?  I'm on Catalina 10.15.2.  Xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 1):

In projects target, "App Sandbox" section, "Hardware" check "USB":

[image: Menu as described above]